# Chef - variables in template

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am new to Chef and wondering how I can pass variables from attributes to a template:

My cookbook name is: `apache`

In my attributes file (default.rb):

```
default['apache']['serverpath'] = '/etc/apache2'
```

In my template (apache.erb), I am trying to use that variable:

```
<% @serverpath %>
```

This this not work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `variables serverpath: node['apache']['serverpath']` to your recipe code.

Comment: Does it matter where I add it? In the top of the recpie?

Comment: In the `template` block. Have look at the [docs](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html), please.